# Product Images too big

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying to finish my website, but at the end I saw that my single product images are way too big.

My settings were set to 600 px x 450px
But when I visit the a product page, they're set to 1100 x 855 px.

I already tried to fix it with this CSS:

```
.single-product div.product div.images img {
    width:              80% !important; 
    margin:             auto;
}
```

and used the plugin to regenerate the thumbnails, but not the solution.

Does anyone have an idea to fix it?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Would setting a `max-width: 600px;` solve the issue for the width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your WordPress go to "WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display" there you can set the Product Images. See the attached image - [image] After setting the image size do image regeneration using plugin -'Regenerate Thumbnails'

Comment: That's what I've already done. With no solution. This doesn't do anything at my website. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the images a fixed width, give it the the container:

```
.single-product .product .images {
  width: 80%; 
  margin: auto;
}

img.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Your images container will now have 80% of the parents width. Your images with the class `.img-responsive` Will use their own width unless the container is smaller. If the container is smaller than your images, they will simply scale down, keeping the proportions. (Same class as bootstrap uses).

Comment: it's still the same size. All the images are way too big. Here's my website, so you can see the problem: https://www.huidengewei.nl/product/schaap-wit/schaap-wit-groot/

Comment: you used `width: 100%;` instead of `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: but that doesn't have any affect on the size. It stils stays enormous.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Regenerate Thumbnails plugin doesn't work. Try looking for "Force Regenerate Thumbnails" and see if that plugin gives you any luck.

Comment: it doesn't do anything to the image size, it's all the same. ;)